# How to implement Single sign on(SSO) in asp.net mvc using OAuth/SAML protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

How to implement Single sign on(SSO) in asp.net mvc 5 application using OAuth/SAML protocol.not by using Forms authentication.

Comment: check this http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc